# Can Linux USB probe order be changed or controlled?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am new to Linux and I need to write a USB driver for a device with 2 interfaces. One interface is HID class (3/0/0) with one interrupt in endpoint and a report descriptor. The other interface is vendor defined with 3 bulk endpoints. In my usb_device_id table I have a USB_DEVICE entry with the VID and PID.

When I plug in the device, my xxx_probe function is called for the vendor defined interface but not for the HID interface. Instead, it appears that a built-in driver called 'generic-usb' is taking control of the HID interface.

Is there a way to ensure that my driver probe function is called first?

Why doesn't Linux make multiple passes looking for a more specific driver first (like Windows does)?

Alternatively, can the 'generic-usb' driver be used to receive data on the interrupt endpoint and to set reports and features on the control pipe?

Comment: I think I've found a kernel patch which fixes this problem: http://lwn.net/Articles/460522/ From patch description: "This should completely solve the problem of getting devices
initialized in the right order." But it isn't done yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that libusb-1.0.8 allows an application to take control of interfaces on an attached device without the need of a custom driver. So far it appears to provide all the support that I need.